# LXC Bridge not working on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, lxc

I'm trying to get lxc containers running with a bridged network connection so the container get ip addresses like the host does from a dhcp server.

I red several tutorials, but I couldn't find one that explicitly mentions 15.04. Mostly they were about ubuntu 12. So maybe that's the problem somehow?

Here is what I tried:

- install ubuntu 15.04 server
- `sudo apt-get install lxc lxctl lxc-templates`
- install lxc webpanel as root: `wget http://lxc-webpanel.github.io/tools/install.sh -O - | bash`

`/etc/network/interfaces` change to the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

- After rebooting I have `lxcbr0` and `br0` in `ifconfig`
- create a lxc container in the webpanel with ubuntu in it
- in the webpanel, configure the new container to use `br0` instead of `lxcbr0`
- start the container

=> the new container's MAC is not seen in the dhcp servers lease list as well logging in to the container with `lxc-console` and running `ifconfig` shows that it doesn't get an IP address.

Btw. If I keep `lxcbr0` the container gets an IP address, but that is masqueraded and not accessible from the outside. But that works.

What's the thing I'm missing here? Maybe some security issue?

[edit]

`brctl show` shows this:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.000c29e793a1       no              eth0
                                                        vethSCX4N3
lxcbr0          8000.000000000000       no
```

Also, the ubuntu 15.04 server is running on an esxi 6.0.
[/edit]

Comment: Could you show what you get by `brctl show` while your container is running?  And is your Ubuntu 15.04 server on another virtualization host like VMware?

Comment: I added the answers to your questions to my question.

Comment: On ESXi you need to allow at least "MAC address changes" and "Forged transmits" for guests to send/receive packets with MAC other than it's assigned.  See [VMware docs](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-3507432E-AFEA-4B6B-B404-17A020575358.html) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yaegashi's VMWare comment pushed me in the right direction. I had to enable promiscuous mode on the Virtual Machine Port Group on the esxi host. Otherwise, the virtual switch won't allow traffic through the port with a mac address different from the the virtual adapter's mac address.